# Database interaction for Rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008, tiny-tds

I have a little question regarding the databases and Rails.

VirtualBox -> Ubuntu
DB -> MSSQL 2008

So I was able to connect my Ubuntu to MSSQL through FreeTDs AND TinyTDs and query the values. Then I implemented it inside the database.yml file. The problem is, when I make the same call from inside the application, I get a -1 (Fixnum), while if I query it when testing for connection, I get the proper results.

App -> database.yml -X> odbc.ini -> odbcinst.ini -> MSSQL

I think that where the X is, that's when my program fails. Inside the app, it properly checks for the connection, even throws errors if I put wrong database name, so I know it is recognizing it. So i truly believe that X step is the problem.

Will post parts in a second.

**APP**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   #self.table_name = "orders"
   def self.try_t
      establish_connection :development
      Order.connection.execute("select count(*) from BBOrders")
   end
end
```

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  dsn: K_Connection
  #dsn: mydsn
  mode: odbc
  #mode: dblib
  encoding: utf8
  database: KTrade
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  username: tr
  password: tr2
```

**odbc.ini**

```
[K_connection]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace=Yes
Server=xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx
Database=KTrade
TDS_Version=7.0
Port=1433
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/local/lib/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout=
CPReuse=
FileUsage=2
UsageCount=2
```

**MSSQL 2008**
Database Name - KTrade.
Table to access - dbo.BBOrders (dbo. can be omitted)

Comment: im using SQL 2008 and im inside Vmware and im getting fixnum too :-(

Comment: ok i just try it out of vmware at windows and its still returning -1

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM table")
```

thx to
http://postal-code.com/binarycode/2011/05/16/raw-sql-queries-and-rails/